# Gollum `_Header.md` will not render

Tags: ruby, wiki, gollum-wiki

Working with [gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) I am unable to get headers to render.  The file is name `_Header.md` following [the specifications](https://github.com/github/gollum#header-files), and contains the following content

```
Hello Header!
```

however, it is not rendered when the site is accessed running `gollum` in the root of the repository and accessing the page at `http://localhost:3000/`.

This is particularly puzzling because I am able to get sidebars and footers to render properly but not headers, what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.0 does not support `_Header.ext` along with `'[[_TOC_]]` which was a lot more obvious that something just isn't right here and this probably isn't me doing something stupid.

Version 2.1 should be released soon.

Comment: @ChristianGoudreau Yes it has, it's at version 2.4 now and supports [exactly what is described](https://github.com/github/gollum#table-of-contents)